# Tkinter make an image smaller without losing detail

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

At the moment I'm using "subsample" so that images don't fill the screen, but I've noticed it loses it quality when doing this.

```
PhotoImage(file=image).subsample(5)
```

[image]

(Left = Image on tkinter, Right = Image on paint)

How can I make the image smaller without losing its quality?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Pillow (formerly known as PIL, which is now deprecated).

Using Pillow you can make an image smaller using the `thumbnail()` function, or if you are looking to increase the size of an image, the `resize()` function will also work.

```
from PIL import Image
size = 128, 128    
im = Image.open(infile)
im.thumbnail(size)
im.save(file + ".thumbnail", "JPEG")
```